# Erasing and appending std::list in concurrently using winapi threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi, stl

I have a class Scheduler that distributes tasks to a collection of "nodes" represented by a vector of lists, each list contains the tasks this particular node is running.

The task struct looks like this.

```
struct Task {
    Task(unsigned int start, unsigned int duration) noexcept :
    start(start), duration(duration) {}
    bool operator == (const Task & rhs) { return start == rhs.start && duration == rhs.duration; }
    bool operator == (const int) { return false; }
    unsigned int start;
    unsigned int duration;
};
// this is needed in std::min_element()
bool operator< (std::list<Task>&, std::list<Task>&);
```

In the Scheduler, each node(list) is given a CRITICAL_SECTION to synchronize w/r to each list.

```
class Scheduler {
public:
    // constructor and destructor
    std::pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> new_task(unsigned int start, unsigned int duration) noexcept;
private:
    static unsigned long _stdcall timer(void*) noexcept;
    static unsigned long _stdcall worker(void*) noexcept;
    std::vector<std::list<Task>> nodes;
    std::vector<CRITICAL_SECTION> cs;
}
```

The new_task() is invoked by a threadpool outside the class.

```
pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> Scheduler::new_task(unsigned int start, unsigned int duration) noexcept
{
    vector<list<Task>>::iterator iter = min_element(nodes.begin(), nodes.end());
    unsigned int index = iter - nodes.begin();
    EnterCriticalSection(&cs[index]);
    iter->emplace_back(move(start), move(duration));
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs[index]);
    return make_pair<unsigned int, unsigned int> (move(index), static_cast<unsigned int>(iter->size()));
}
```

Both timer and worker are started in their separate threads in the constructor. The timer sleeps for 1 second and sets event to wake up worker, which iterates through all nodes and process tasks by decrementing their duration, and removing it when it finishes.

```
unsigned long _stdcall Scheduler::worker(void*) noexcept {
    bool changed;
    while (!WaitForSingleObject(self->clean, INFINITE))
    for (size_t i = 0; i < self->nodes.size(); i++) {
        changed = false;
        auto end = self->nodes[i].end();
        for (auto iter = self->nodes[i].begin(); iter != end;) {
            if (--iter->duration == 0) {
                changed = true;
                EnterCriticalSection(&self->cs[i]);
                iter = self->nodes[i].erase(iter);
                end = self->nodes[i].end();
                LeaveCriticalSection(&self->cs[i]);
                continue;
            }
            iter++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get "list iterators incompatible" from std::list header when doing iter != end after several successful removal/erase() in workers. I also have std::foward(Task const &) access violation, which I guess happened at "emplace_back" in new_task ().

My initial thought is that both problems are caused by insufficient synchronization of list mutations, but I cannot think of where I might have missed. Any thoughts are appreciated!

PS: Those who wants to make me consider cross-platform and rewrite the class with std::thread, I am just doing a demo and learning winapi, thank you for your advice in advance!

Comment: `bool operator< (std::list<Task>, std::list<Task>)`  -- These should be passed by const reference, not by value.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, fixed. The main problem is still there though.

Comment: any reason why the critical section is not part of the task itself?

Comment: @DavidHaim Critical sections are created one per list to synchronize list emplace_back() in new_task() and erase() in work(), while each list has arbitratry number of tasks.

Comment: Iterators in std::vector are invalidated by operations that change the size of the vector. Could that be your problem?

Comment: *"a vector of lists"* - That sounds very wrong. Any modification to the vector will invalidate all iterators. Iterators into lists only get invalidated, when any particular item is removed. All other iterators remain valid.

Comment: @Arkadiy In my case the size of the vector is fixed throughout the lifetime of the Scheduler object, I have not started on implementing the resizing of vector, so until now the problem you mentioned should not happen.

Comment: @IInspectable Please see above about resizing vectors. And about the list iterator, I agree with your words. But the debug assertion "list iterators incompatible" comes off of operator== comparing two iterators, at iter != end. I am still very confused.

Comment: Just because list iterators aren't invalidated when the list changes doesn't mean list changes are *thread-safe*. You're reading from the list in both `new_task()` and `worker()` without the list being locked; if one thread locks and modifies the list, the other thread can still be reading from the list as it's being modified. You need locking around **all** list access if it can be modified simultaneously by another thread.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Good points. Just to make sure, since `std::min_element()` in `new task()` invokes `size()` on all lists, do I have to lock every lists for each `min_element()` call, even if I can accept not up-to-date results ? And I have to lock the whole inner loop of `worker()` right?

Comment: To be safe, yes. You can use a [SRW lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx) if you want to minimise contention while reading.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks! I will look into it.